# Given a pair of pitches, does this chart correctly show the number of scales containing that pair?

Tags: theory, scales, intervals

I posted this chart on my page. I created it based on exercise 6 of chapter 1 of Harmony by Piston, to be a kind of help, but as I'm not sure if it's correct or not (if it's not I will take it down to not spread misinformation). I ask your help.

The idea behind the chart is to know how many scales contain a specific pair of pitches, organized by interval. For example, for any given minor second (e.g., C-Db), there are two major scales contain that specific minor second (Ab major and Db major). Similarly, for a given perfect fifth (e.g., D-A), there are four harmonic minor scales containing that specific fifth (D, F#, G, A).

Edit: Add the chart image here so it's not self-promotion:

[image: Chart]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133818/discussion-on-question-by-aelianus-adolphus-given-a-pair-of-pitches-does-this-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how the chart should look, but with augmented and diminished intervals included. It counts how may of a particular interval may be achieved using each scale degree as that interval's lower pitch. For example, within a major scale, there are two scale degrees from which a minor second can be formed — degrees 3 and 7 — and there are two scale degrees from which a major seventh can be formed — degrees 1 and 4. Errors in the OP table are given in boldface type.

| Interval | Major | Nat. Minor | Har. Minor | Mel. Minor (asc.) | Har. Major | Total occurrences |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| m2 | 2 | 2 | **3** | **2** | 3 | **12** |
| M2 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 21 |
| A2 |  |  | 1 |  | 1 | 02 |
| m3 | 4 | 4 | **4** | **4** | 4 | **20** |
| M3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 15 |
| d4 |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 03 |
| P4 | 6 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 24 |
| A4 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 08 |
| d5 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 08 |
| P5 | 6 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 24 |
| A5 |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 03 |
| m6 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 15 |
| M6 | 4 | 4 | **4** | **4** | 4 | **20** |
| d7 |  |  | 1 |  | 1 | 02 |
| m7 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 21 |
| M7 | 2 | 2 | **3** | **2** | 3 | **12** |

Note that in the above table:

1. Groups of intervals with the same number (e.g., m2, M2, A2) will always add to seven occurrences.
2. Intervals that are inversions of each other (e.g., m2 and M7) will always have the same number. In other words, the top and bottom halves of the table are mirror images.

Comment: @Aelianus_Adolphus Perhaps I misunderstood. My chart says that every harmonic minor scale contains three minor seconds.

Comment: However, this should be equivalent. For example, in harmonic minor, the three minor seconds occur between scale degrees 2-3, 5-6, and 7-8. Taking your example of C-Db, that can occur in three scales — once as scale degrees 2-3 (Bb harmonic minor), once as 5-6 (F harmonic minor), and once as 7-8 (Db harmonic minor). So in your earlier comment, you just left out Db harmonic minor.